# How do I get bitmapcontext for retina and find specific pixel inside it?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, core-graphics

I have tried to figure this out for a while with no success. I'm making an app that returns color from a given point. When i input a point it will sometimes work but it will not be on the right pixel and completely random. So my thought is that the bytes is in the wrong order. A quick calculations shows that there is 2908160 bytes allocated using the retina iPhone for a 640*1136 sized view. However there is more bits in offset when both points is at 320 and 568 which shows that there is something wrong here. So is there any way to fix this?

int offset = (4*scaleFactor)*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));

I also wonder how I can call the free(data). When I try to call it the app will crash and return an error message with something like "you cannot free data not allocated using malloc".

I would be glad for an answer that shows my how to fix this because this is making me crazy.

I would like you to look specifically at:

```
 unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cacheContext);
    if (data != NULL) {
        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int offset = (4*scaleFactor)*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
```

and

```
       //  if (data) { free(data); }
    data = nil;
```

Full code:

```
- (BOOL) initContext:(CGSize)size {

    float scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    // scaleFactor = 2;

    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height)*scaleFactor*scaleFactor;

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    cacheBitmap = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (cacheBitmap == NULL){
        return NO;
    }

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (cacheBitmap, size.width*scaleFactor, size.height *scaleFactor, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow*scaleFactor, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

    CGContextScaleCTM(cacheContext, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
       CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cacheContext, 1, 0, 0, 0.0);
   CGContextFillRect(cacheContext, (CGRect){CGPointZero, CGSizeMake(size.height*scaleFactor, size.width*scaleFactor)});

    return YES;
}

- (UIColor*) getPixelColorForContext:(CGContextRef)cgctx size:(CGSize)ctxSize atLocation:(CGPoint)point
{
    UIColor* color = nil;
    // Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
   // if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

        float scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    //scaleFactor = 2;

    NSLog(@"%.0f",framsize.width);
    size_t w = framsize.width*scaleFactor*scaleFactor;

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cacheContext);
    if (data != NULL) {
        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int offset = (4*scaleFactor)*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
        int alpha =  data[offset];
        int red = data[offset+1];
        int green = data[offset+2];
        int blue = data[offset+3];
        NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }

    // Free image data memory for the context
    //  if (data) { free(data); }
    data = nil;

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Do not repost previous questions. If needed, update the previous question.

Comment: it's not a duplicate and can you please stop downvote.

Comment: It sure looks like the same question. Even has nearly the same code.